# Java Using the return value of a loop within the loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, random, return

sorry but english is nut my first language. I'm building a main class and method to create a bunch of random numbers. I want to use a  for-loop and want to use with every step of the loop the result of the last loop.

The User is asked to enter 3 integers to create a random number with the formula: 
z =  (a*z+b)%m;

1.Step
z = (a*0+b)%m;  Lets say the result is 7.
2. Step:
z= (a*7+b)%m
and so on.

I want the program to give me 20 random numbers.
In the first step of the loop the random number z is 0, and then with every additional step the random number is built from the result of the last step.
I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say.

My Code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Zufallszahlentest {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Geben Sie nacheinander die Werte für a,b &m ein.");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int m = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        Methode(a,b,m);
        System.out.println(Methode(a,b,m));
    }

    static int Methode(int a, int b, int m){
            int z = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                 z = (a*z+b)%m;
            }
            return z;
     }
}
```

I've been sitting on this for hours, I've built huge loops with no result and I feel like getting dumber and dumber with every try.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: make z a static int

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is in the wrong place - it should include the println, if you want println to happen 20 times.. This should work:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Zufallszahlentest {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Geben Sie nacheinander die Werte für a,b &m ein.");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int m = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int z = Methode(a, b, m, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(z);
            z = Methode(a, b, m, z);
        }
    }

    static int Methode(int a, int b, int m, int z) {
        return (a * z + b) % m;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow guys, thank you so much. Again I was thinking way too complicated. I started building loofs with if/else statements and what not. I guess that this line : int z = Methode(a, b, m, 0); is the point I could'nt wrap my head around, but now it's clear. Thanks again, guys.